# Efficient way to generate all combinations of a list regardless of order

Tags: python, combinations

I have the following code snippet that is quite inefficient: It aims to produce 27 different combinations of **exactly** **3** **numbers** for each combination

```
nums = [i for i in range(1,4)]
combinations = []
for i in nums:
  for j in nums:
    for k in nums:
      combinations.append([i,j,k])
```

This generates 27 combinations which is correct.

Is there a more efficient way to generate this and how can I store into a dataframe instead of a list ?

Comment: not sure why this is tagged to another question. its definitely not the same

Comment: @Selcuk you pointed to questions wanting `combinations` but Roger is clearly wanting `itertools.product` you should have pointed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists or similar

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen im not sure that its product because it wouldn't give me 27 combinations with a list of 3 numbers ( 3^3).

Comment: `itertools.product(nums, repeat=3)` is what you are looking for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384109/iterate-over-all-combinations-of-values-in-multiple-lists-in-python might have been a better target.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You are correct, updated the duplicate. Confused by the wording used in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634489/get-all-combinations-of-elements-from-two-lists is probably the best target as it is both asking for combinations (but meaning product) from lists and about `DataFrame`, It really bugs me how hard it is to find those existing questions even when you know what to look for just because "combinations" is used in plain english to mean both "cartesian product" and "mathematical sequence combinations" and occasionally permutations too.